# React Native app crashes on launch with Invariant Violation

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a react native app built using Expo and everything was working fine until I had to `npm install` a package that broke everything. I've uninstalled the said package but the app doesn't seem to work any more. It shows the following invariant violation:

[image: Error Image]

It shows an error `Invariant Violation: ListView has been removed from React Native` - however, I have not used ListView anywhere in my project. All my lists are through `FlatList` or `VirtualisedList`.

Additionally, I'm unable to deduce from the error info about the origin of this error. How do I fix this?

Comment: delete node_modules folder by `rm -rf node_modules` then run `npm install` and restart your react-native packager `npm start --reset-cache` then run project

Comment: Already done that - didn't help.

Comment: listview is removed from react native with latest version so please use flatlist any other ready made component

Comment: @GauravWadhwani have you managed to fix this?

Comment: A package i installed was using the deprecated ListView. Ended up replacing that package.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the backup of the code please check the older version of React Native in package.json.
When you do npm install command your React Native version upgraded or may be some other packages.

So, you need to compare the packages with old package.json file. If you found that some packages are updated then you need to remove ^ e.g react-native: ^0.60.0 from package dependencies. This one is the only way to solve this problem.